# Facebook login on IOS but if requested

Tags: ios, facebook

In the most tutorials concerning Facebook login on IOS, as soon you launch your app, you need to identify you. I don't want the loginView as my first view.

My first view is a menu where user can select 3 choices and if he chooses n°3, so he can login on fb.

How can modify my code please ?

```
    - (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:(NSDictionary *)launchOptions {

    // Function called to create a copy of the database if needed.
    [self createCopyOfDatabaseIfNeeded];


    self.window = [[UIWindow alloc] initWithFrame:[[UIScreen mainScreen] bounds]];
    // Override point for customization after application launch.
    self.window.backgroundColor = [UIColor whiteColor];

    /*
     Here I create the root view controller, and a navigation
     controller to contain it. I then set the window's root
     controller equal to the navigation controller.
     */
    LBRootViewController *rootViewController =
    [[LBRootViewController alloc] init];

    UINavigationController *navController =
    [[UINavigationController alloc]
     initWithRootViewController:rootViewController];

    self.window.rootViewController = navController;


   [self.window makeKeyAndVisible];
```

Answer (score 1):

That's easy enough... but doesn't have much to do with the coding from the App Delegate you've placed here so far…  To do what you described, the Facebook login needs to be handled in a view controller at the point where you'd actually like to execute the login.

If you're using a FBLoginView, to prevent the user from logging in the from first screen, don't place the:

```
- (void)loginViewShowingLoggedInUser:(FBLoginView *)loginView
```

code in the initial view controller, so it doesn't automatically log in an active user.  I suggest putting those three login selections on one view controller, then transitioning to another to handle the actual login.